# How to set database login information from variable?

Tags: java, mybatis

I am using MyBatis in a Java project. I know that database access information such as host, database name, username and password are stored in `configuration.xml`. But I would like to know if I can set these login information from inside my Java program.

It's because my application is accessing different databases on different addresses and I am configuring them in the application. Please help me.

Comment: Do you need to connect to different DBs at the same time? Or, do you just need different DB info for different environments (dev, test, prod,...)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the existing answers were not enough to help me out with the same problem, here is my solution. It works with myBatis 3.2.1.

### 1. In `mybatis-config.xml`

- Add those property elements you want to set from inside Java to the `<property>` section.
- Refer to those elements in the `<dataSource>` section using `${*property*}` as value.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <property name="url" value=""/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </properties>            
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>  
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
                <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
                <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
    ...
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

### 2. In Java

Create a `Properties` object, add the properties you selected to set manually and pass it to the `build()` method when obtaining the `SqlSessionFactory`:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("username", "myUser");
properties.setProperty("password", "myPwd");
properties.setProperty("url", "myConnectionURL");

InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream("mybatis-config.xml");
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream, properties);
```

Answer (score 4):

The configuration xml file supports a `<properties>` element. You can either point to an external file (through the `resource` attribute) or define each `<property>` directly in the xml.

Properties can be referenced elsewhere in the Mybatis config and mapper xml files with `${property}` syntax like this (from the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties)):

```
<properties resource="org/mybatis/example/config.properties"> 
  <property name="username" value="dev_user"/> 
  <property name="password" value="F2Fa3!33TYyg"/> 
</properties> 

<dataSource type="POOLED"> 
  <property name="driver" value="${driver}"/> 
  <property name="url" value="${url}"/> 
  <property name="username" value="${username}"/> 
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/> 
</dataSource>
```

Note that property elements *override* any properties defined in the file.

Comment: So i tried to create property like this but its probably not what should i do. SO I have to create file config.propeties like u wrote but how can i send my dynamic data to those propeties?
This is what I tried:
`Properties props = null;
            props.setProperty("username", "root");
            
            Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("wsnscc/mybatis/xml/Configuration.xml");
            FACTORY = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, props);`

Comment: That should work. Can you verify that `FACTORY.getConfiguration().getVariables().getProperty("username")` returns the expected value?

Comment: I think i got it but now iam trying to find out how to send variable with data to mybatissqlsessionfactory class. Iam creating  factory like this:
`session = MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
        mapper = session.getMapper(StaticMapper.class);`
But i need variable with login info somehow set the propeties inside MyBatisSqlSessionFactory

Comment: The Configuration is read only once the SqlSessionFactory is created. If you are trying to connect to multiple DBs, you need to create one SqlSessionFactory for each DB.

Comment: My problem isnt that iam using multiple db. I just dont know how to send those properties from main program to static class MyBatisSqlSessionFactory where are database properties being set.

Do I just have to create in main program some file with propeties and then i can create create a session when factory is reading the same file with conf? I would appreciate some code sample...

Comment: The code in your first comment looks correct for this, except for `props = null`. You can load the Properties with something like: `props = Properties.load(Resources.getResourceAsStream("file.properties"))`.

Comment: The link to the documentation is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the existing answers were not enough to help me out with the same problem, here is my solution. It works with myBatis 3.0.3.

mybatis-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <property name="url" value=""/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </properties>            
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>  
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
                <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
                <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
                <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
    ...
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Java Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("username", userName);
properties.setProperty("password", password);
properties.setProperty("url", dbURL);

Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, properties);
```

**Note:** For myBatis 3.0.3, SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build() method does not take InputStream as a parameter as suggested in answer by user905686, you should use the Reader instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do using Spring 4 and @Configuration in Data Config

[How to set fetchSize for iBatis select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851044/how-to-set-fetchsize-for-ibatis-select-statement/44010843#44010843)

The difference is the way you can load config file

```
@Value("classpath:mybatis-config.xml")
private Resource myBatisResource ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself datasource which extends form BasicDataSource, as follows.

```
package org.popkit.mydatasource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyDataSource extends BasicDataSource implements InitializingBean {

public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    String url = this.getUrl();

    // following do as yourself
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(url)) {
        this.setUrl("#your jdbc.url");
    }
    String username = this.getUsername();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(username)) {
        this.setUsername("#your jdbc.username");
    }
    String password = this.getPassword();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
        this.setPassword("#your jdbc.pwd");
    }
}
```

}

in xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.popkit.mydatasource.MyDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value=""/>
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="3" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="30" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

First write the information regarding driver,username,password in some file and read that file contents in your java application

Properties properties=new Properties();

properties.load("INPUTSTREAM");

Comment: And then? Your answer doesn't seem complete.